# Why does every npm ip package give me 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.xx.xx?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, ip-address

Apologies for the simple question but I have been unable to figure out what is happening here. I am building a react.js app which accesses an express back end from a different port.
Right now I am using fetch to do so as such

```
 fetch("http://192.168.0.126:9000/testAPI")
```

While it would be ideal to use localhost instead of the local ipv4, the purpose is to access from another device. I have been trying, and failing, to use different node packages, like [local-ip-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-ip-url), to concatenate into a string, and while that works, it only gives the 127.0.0.1 address, which does not work on another device on the network. Most basically, at the beginning of my App.js file I have these 2 lines of code

```
const localIpUrl = require('local-ip-url');
console.log(localIpUrl('public', 'ipv4'))
```

And out on the console comes 127.0.0.1, despite the 'public' being included. I am very stuck on this, and would appreciate any light on why this is happening.

Thanks heaps.

edit: just wanted to add that the ip is found using address.ip() in WebpackDevServerUtils.js, which react uses (from my understanding) to print the URL to the terminal after compiling. When I try this in my App.js, the variable is undefined, so I think I am doing something wrong

Comment: Could you clarify if `App.js` is a part of your React app (so this code is run in a browser, not in Node)?

Comment: Hi, have you solved it? I am facing the same issue.